# Wordpress backend:How to hide some specific pages under Pages-->All Pages

Tags: pages

I have some pages with shortcodes and I don't want my client to see the pages with shortcodes. Is there a way to hide these pages under Pages-->All Pages,but should be seen under Menu.Is there a plugin to achieve this?I have searched but found none.

Comment: What do you mean by seen under the menu? Please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code snippet into one of my project. Use the code snippet into the `functions.php` within the main PHP tag:

```
// HIDE SOME PAGES FROM THE EYE OF EDITOR

function wpse20131126_exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;
    if (is_admin() && current_user_can('editor') && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type =='page') {
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array(
                        '77', // the security page
                        '74', // the shortcoded page
                        '111' // the abracadabra page
                        );
    }
}

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse20131126_exclude_pages_from_admin' );
```

Add your pages inside the array to hide from the eye of User role '`Editor`'.